# What is an appropriate way to write a recursive SMARTS that excludes trifluoromethyl groups as a potential R group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry

C[CX4&!$(C(F)(F)F)] is the smarts I've tried. It does not exclude the trifluoride in CC(F)(F)F.

Comment: +1 Although you might get better answers on Matter Modelling SE

Comment: If I see it correctly, you want to exclude C(F)(F)F, but find all other C?

Comment: By the way did you post the same question on Matter Modelling SE, from a different user account? : https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/excluding-certain-sp3-hybridized-carbons-with-smarts . If not, it is asking the same question about excluding trifluoromethyl so it might be helpful. If you have asked the other question too, and this answer satisfies your question, then feel free to close the other one, because cross-posting is usually discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand your intent.  My assumptions are

- you have a set of molecules, e.g., as a list of SMILES strings (say `FC(c1ccccc1)(F)F`, `CCCC(F)(F)F`, `CC(Cl)(Cl)Cl`, and `CCCO`) in a file like `probe.smi`
- you want to identify the molecules *without* the $\ce{-CF3}$ group

If so, I would *i*) search for the molecules *with* said group in a first step and then *ii*) remove this sub-set of positives from the set to know about the molecules without the $\ce{-CF3}$ group.

- [OpenBabel](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel)'s positives: `obabel -ismi probe.smi -s'C(F)(F)F' -osmi -O positives.smi`.  In the present example, this yields only `FC(c1ccccc1)(F)F` and `CCCC(F)(F)F`, regardless of the different notation of the trifluormethyl group in the entries concerned.
- The molecules lacking the $\ce{-CF3}$ group are just the complementary sub-set to the sub-set of the positives.  To start, one could opt for a Python script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""Report molecules lacking the -CF3 group."""


def reporter():
    """Report .smi of molecules without -CF3 group."""
    # prepare lists about the molecules:
    all_mols = []  # all molecules, no discern
    positives = []  # molecules with -CF3
    negatives = []  # molecules without -CF3

    with open('probe.smi', mode='r') as source:
        for line in source:
            all_mols.append(line.strip())

    with open('positives.smi', mode='r') as source:
        for line in source:
            positives.append(line.strip())

    # truncate the set to yield the sub-set about molecules without -CF3 group:
    set_all_mols = set(all_mols)
    set_positives = set(positives)
    set_negatives = set_all_mols.difference(set_positives)

    # convert the sub-set (back) into a list of entries:
    negatives = list(set_negatives)

    with open('negatives.smi', mode='w') as newfile:
        newfile.write('\n'.join(negatives))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    reporter()
```

which in file `negatives.smi` correctly reports `CC(Cl)(Cl)Cl` and `CCCO` as molecules without the $\ce{-CF3}$ group.

---

Of course it would be nice to identify how to negate OpenBabel's search filter (`-s'C(F)(F)F'`) to shorten the route traveled here.